# Variable not defined error upon execution

Tags: excel, vba

can someone explain why I get a variable not defined error on this private sub?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
'Autocomplete Button
Dim w As Long, lastRow As Long
For w = 2 To lastRow
   'If existing data = entered data
    If sh.Cells(w, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value Then
    'fill textbox with associated existing data from same row
        Me.TextBox2.Value = sh.Cells(w, 3).Value
    'save value of i in invisible textbox because no better solution came to mind yet
        Me.TextBox8.Value = w
        Exit Sub
        End If
Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because you're never assigning `lastRow` a value

Comment: Whats sh? it just appears but isn't declared in the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you used a variable but did not declare it before. This variable looks like to be `sh`. So if `sh` is not a global variable then you need to delare it and set it to your desired worksheet before using the variable:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")
```

---

Also note that `lastRow` has no value and therefore is `0` before you use it you need to set a value for this variable.

Otherwise `For w = 2 To lastRow` is just `For w = 2 To 0` and therefore will never run.